# I Created A Bot With MS Bot Framework to Use Slack Now I Can't Get the Slack login and password

Tags: azure, bots, botframework

I created a bot using the MS Bot Framework that interfaces with colleagues using Slack. Now I was hoping to login to slack using that handle and am unable to get the login email address and password from the MS Bot Framework. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't login to Slack as the bot. Once you [configure the Slack channel](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html#channels) for your Bot in the Bot Framework portal, you should be able to see the Bot as part of your Slack contacts and invite him to any channel.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that I can't login to Slack as the bot. That is what I was hoping to do. I just wanted to have the ability to take down the bot and respond to people manually in the event of a large or offensive malfunction by the bot.

Comment: ACK. To take down the bot you can "disable" the slack integration temporarily. Additionally, you can kick the bot from the channel, however that won't prevent users having direct conversation with the bot. Please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Within the Bot Framework portal you can also disable the bot entirely on the edit details page; it'll stop being able to send messages through the Bot Framework.